# AngularJS $timeout freezes during refresh No New Data Uploaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, timeout, promise

I'm trying to make a simple feed where you traditionally pull down to refresh latest content, and scroll down to view old content.

THE PROBLEM: I want to delay for 1 second, push content to the front of the feed array (via unshift) then call the refreshComplete broadcast. But when I run the code, the "refreshing" state never exits (it freezes in refreshing)...What am I doing wrong?

```
$scope.doNewContent = function() {   
  $timeout( function() {
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});

        //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    }, 1000);
  };
```

I tried this also:

```
   $timeout( 1000).then(
     function() {
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});

        //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
```

This didn't work either. (If the code above has any misplaced brackets, please assume that I coded it correctly).

When I code it like this:

```
   $scope.doNewContent = function() { 
      $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});

        //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
   };
```

it works but ONLY for like two pull downs. Then it will go through the refresh process, but the list no longer updates.

---

Here is the complete controller code.

```
.controller('FeedCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;

  $scope.loadHistory = function() {
 $scope.feed.push({ id: $scope.feed.length});

 if ( $scope.feed.length == 99 ) {
  $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
}
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  };

  $scope.doNewContent = function() {   
  $timeout( function() {
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});
        $scope.feed.unshift({id: ($scope.feed.length-100000)});

        //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    }, 1000);
  };  

  $scope.feed = [];
});
```